# psycopg2.Error isn't being caught in python try/except block

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am developing an application using django with a PostgreSQL database. The application is designed to be used within an organization, so user-supplied SQL requests need to be executed. To deal with the possibility of malformed SQL requests, the database calls are wrapped in a try/except block:

```
import psycopg2
...
def djangoView(request):
    ...
    try:
        result = DBModel.objects.raw(sqlQuery)
        return getJSONResponse(result) #Serializes result of query to JSON
    except psycopg2.Error:
        pass #Handle error (no db requests are made)
```

However, when I make a request to the view with malformed SQL, I am greeted with a 500 internal server error. The stack trace reveals that the cause of the 500 is a ProgrammingError, which is a subclass of psycopg2.Error. However, the except statement doesn't catch it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django wraps all database exceptions with exceptions from its `django.db` [package](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions).

A correct way to catch the Error is:

```
import django.db
...
except django.db.Error:
```

If you want to access the underlying database exception:

```
except django.db.Error as e:
    dbException = e.__cause__ #Subclass of psycopg2.Error
```